# How to remove a value from group by using filter?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

This is the data:

```
ID  Group   test
11  1   test1
11  2   test1
11  2   test2
12  1   test1
12  2   test1
```

If a group did two tests, I want to only keep the `test2`.
If a group did only one test, I will keep that test.

For example, here, I want to delete the `test1` in Group 2 for ID 11.

I tried the following code:

```
data %>%group_by(ID, Group) %>%filter(test == "test2")
```

But it did not work well, because all the `test1` will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility: add an auxiliary variable that counts the number of tests in the group.

```
(data 
      %>% group_by(ID, Group) 
      %>% mutate(n=n()) 
      %>% filter(n==1 | test=="test2")
)
```

(you can `select(-n)` afterwards if you want to get rid of that variable).

Actually (after further experimentation), looks like you can use `n()` on the fly:

```
(data 
     %>% group_by(ID, Group) 
     %>% filter(n()==1 | test=="test2")
)
```